# Scrum Board for a distributed team

Tags: scrum, collaboration

I am looking for recommendations on a digital Scrum Board which can be shared over the internet. I imagine something like a big tablet on which you can draw and which remote users can access, too.

I dislike Scrum software because I think one major benefit of a Scrum Board is its physical presence. It should be hard to ignore.

The best solution would be two big tablets on which you can draw and which can be synchronized.

Has anyone got product recommendations for something like this? Or would you rather use a software?

Kind regards,
Falcon

Comment: Can you consider rephrasing your question to ask for how one can emulate having a physical scrum board for a distributed team instead of asking for product recommendations?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

[Scrumy](http://scrumy.com/) is by far the best software that I've found. It's just the board, it's lightweight, easy to use and easy to handle. Just what you want.

Most of the other things we evaluated were bloatware. It's like the spirit of agile manifested itself in this software.

> Why does Scrumy exist?
>
> We were attempting to use Scrum to manage our
>   projects, but the generic sticky notes we bought kept falling off the
>   wall. We looked for online solutions to scrum, but all of them were
>   too complicated and expensive. All we really wanted was an online
>   version of our wall sticky notes. So we made one.

Comment: it would be helpful if you list some of _the other things... evaluated_. In other comments, you mentioned Trello, what were other?

Comment: You can downvote me if you want, but Scrumy is still the best digital scrumboard out there. Trello sucks for this purpose, albeit being the highest voted answer. Which shows again, that the masses are not always right...

Answer (score 10):

Check out Trello (trello.com) from Fog Creek Software. It's a kanban style board with live updates and can be used by multiple people. It's power is its simplicity. The tool doesn't get in the way so you can actually use it without getting mired down in process.

Comment: Trello is way too cumbersome. I like scrumy: http://scrumy.com/

Comment: As this website is at least partially owned by Joel Spolsky and Fog Creek is his company, I think there's a reasonable chance that my criticism of trello won't be unheard: I was searching for a digital replacement of a scrumboard. In Trello, the scrum board is a click too far away. I want to see it immediatelly. Then the vertical structure of the boards was irritating. Not what I was looking for. I don't want to adapt to the software. I want a software that fits my needs. I want tasks that look like tiny post it notes. Then, when you click on a task, there comes this big and daunting dialog.

Comment: I don't need those features. I don't want them at all. They're just distracting me from the thing I really want to do. There're far too many options and configuration possibilities. In my opinion, on a scrum board, less is more. Don't make me think!

Comment: Also, I think this post is upvoted by the fog creek people, as Joel Spolsky is involved in this whole site. Regular users know that. I cannot believe, that for the plain and simple use case of replacing a scrum board, this is supposed to be the ideal software. It is certainly not.

Comment: But by far the biggest problem of using Trello for Scrum is, that you cannot easily and obviously put your tasks in relation to stories. It's like a row header that is missing.

Comment: I think you are being a little silly when you say Trello is being upvoted because Fog Creek is moderately associated with SO. I upvoted because trello is one of the best pieces of free software I have ever used. Your problems with it are very particular. I recommend you write your own tool. That is probably the only way you'll be happy.

Comment: Trello is fantastic, but it's **not designed** to be a scrum board, so criticizing it on that point is quite unfair. Go to https://trello.com/tour and you won't see scrum or kanban mentioned anywhere. Hell you wont even see software development.

Comment: And that's exactly why it isn't a suitable software for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

Try out [KanbanTool](http://kanbantool.com) - online kanban board for organizing work and team collaboration.

<sub>The visualization on a board originates from the [Kanban](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kanban_%28development%29) process. [Scrum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrum_%28development%29) is a lot like Kanban. You could call it a concrete Kanban method, thinking in terms of software development.</sub>

This application has nice and smart drag & drop interface. If you need, you can modify card's template and board using swimlanes and columns. It also offers features dedicated for distributed teams such as: real time collaboration, permission levels, email notifications for task assigning and comments, adding tasks and comments via email. Moreover, KanbanTool provides powerful analytics for monitoring and improving your work. It works.

Comment: question is about Scrum, can you elaborate on how "kanban tool" fits here?

Comment: @gnat: The visualization on a board originates from the Kanban process. Scrum is a lot like Kanban. You could call it a concrete Kanban method, thinking in terms of software development.

Answer (score 1):

When we started our recent Scrum implementation, the team was located in the same office, but we wanted the capacity to be able to work in a distributed manor in case we had another earthquake here in Christchurch.

We settled on using a Trello to handle the backlog, and a Google Spreadsheet to mirror our physical board. This means that if anyone is working remotely, they have access to the User Story and Acceptance Criteria from Trello, and a view of the current state of the tasks from the spreadsheet.

The spreadsheet also produces the burn down for the sprint, and provides a lot of the stats that we examine during the Sprint Retrospective, so it's provided a lot of benefits.

Unfortunately we never went any further looking for an online visual representation of the board, since everyone was quite happy with the physical board. Trello is nice for moving tasks between To Be Done/Doing/Done, but it doesn't have the nice snow-plough effect that you get on a physical board.

We did look briefly at [SeeNowDo](https://seenowdo.com/), which is free, and "Looks" like a scrum board, and I've heard of other distributed teams using is successfully, so it might be worth checking out.

If you're interested, I've written a [series of posts](http://www.littlebluemonkey.com/blog/) about our search for an online Scrum board, how we import a backlog into Trello, and back up our Trello boards into a Google Spreadsheet.

Answer (score 1):

Give [Boardsync](http://boardsyncnow.com) a go if you love physical task boards but need to work in a distributed environment.

Take a photo every day and boardsync updates and synchronises a very simple software board.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple simple options.

First, you could use software, and use a flat panel on the wall to display it.  You lose the quick ability to edit at a physical board, but gain instant updates at all ends of the distributed team.

Second, depending how many distributed people exist, if it's only 1 of the team, you could have a physical board at the main location, and just point a webcam at it for the distributed member(s).  However for them to make updates, they would need to contact a person near the board to make the update for them.

Comment: The webcam thing has been tried by a team before, but it won't work, because, as you stated, the process becomes cumbersome. And you cannot just look at the board, you'd have to have a camera which you can remote control and with a very high resolution in order to read the task-notes. Unfortunatelly, it did not work for this team. This team switched back to exchanging excel sheets.